# How much larger would the IceCube Neutrino Observatory be to detect emissions from betelgeuse

Tags: neutrinos, supernova

How much larger would the IceCube Neutrino Observatory be to detect emissions from betelgeuse.

I read that it is currently too far for us to detect whether a supernova is imminent. Would a larger version of the icecube observatory enable us to detect the current state of the core of betelgeuse

Comment: This seems like a complicated question that would require multiple steps. Could you edit your post to include what you've tried so far?

Comment: does the pre-supernovae signal consist of seeing silicon-to-nickel fusion and/or nickel-to-iron decay neutrinos for a few days?